# How to notify exception thrown in a background thread(T1) to scheduler thread(T2)

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, executorservice

I have a scheduler which picks up the jobs at regular interval of times, each job takes long time to process. While a job is  processing, we send heartbeat which updates the last_update_time column in database on a background thread every 5mins until the job is completely finished.

**Question**: If runtime exception is thrown on background thread while sending heartbeat, how to notify the scheduler thread which is processing a job in runJob method to  abort current job immediately and move to next job in the jobs list?

JobRunner.class

```
    @Scheduled
    public void pipelineRunner() {
        List<Job> jobs = getJobs(); //fetches tasks from database
        for(Job job: jobs){
            try{
                heartBeatSender.startHeartBeat(job); // updates last_update_time column for the current job in database on background thread
                runJob(job); // contains logic of processing a job, how to abort current job  it is processing if heartbeat sender throws a runtime exception or how to notify or make scheduler thread throw exception so that it can move to next job in the list?
            }catch(Exception e){}
            finally{
                heartBeatSender.stopHeartBeat(); //stops updating last_update_time col.
            }
        }
    }
```

HeartBeatSender.class

```
  
    public void startHeartBeat(Job job) {
        Runnable heartBeat = () -> {
            if (job != null) {
                job.setLastUpdateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                jobRepository.save(job);//runtime exception can be thrown here.
            }
        }
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(heartBeat, 0L, heartBeatInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);  //heartBeatInterval every 5mins
    }
```

Comment: What thread exactly do you want to send the exception to? And at what point in the code would you say it will be so it can handle it properly?

Comment: If background thread throws runtime exception on .save(job) method, I want it to be notified to scheduler thread  which is executing runJob method so that it aborts the current job and move to the next job.Updated the question.Thanks

Comment: I don't really see the problem in your code (except the scheduling took place in the `Runnable` you declare, I edited the question to correct this). Are you asking how to cancel the heartbeat you schedule? Because you do start a new heartbeat for the next job after the exception. It would be best to post a [mcve] exposing the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is a bit inconsistent in that it seems the `HeartbeatSender` can send heartbeats to several jobs, but the client code always only triggers one. However, if you have another class also using this `HeartbeatSender`, you will have scheduled two heartbeat runnables, so how would it decide which one `stopHeartbeat()` will cancel? Not to mention I wouldn't be able to tell how it cancels it in the first place, because it doesn't keep track of the scheduled task beyond the `startHeartbeat()` call.

So what you may want to do is to have `HeartbeatSender` track its heartbeats by job, so it can cancel them individually.

```
class HeartbeatSender {
  private final Map<Job, ScheduledFuture<?>> heartbeats = new HashMap<>();
  // you can create a new executor in start, but I don't see why
  private final ScheduledExecutorService heartbeatExecutor = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

  public void startHeartbeat(Job job) {
    Runnable heartBeat= ...;
    ScheduledFuture<?> schedule = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(heartBeat, 0L, heartBeatInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    heartbeats.put(job, schedule); // remember so you can cancel later
  }

  public void stopHeartbeat(Job job) {
    ScheduledFuture<?> schedule = heartbeats.remove(job);
    if (schedule != null) {
      schedule.cancel(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can stop heartbeats by job, so you just have to do that in you client code.

```
for(Job job: jobs){
  try {
    heartBeatSender.startHeartBeat(job);
    runJob(job);
  } catch(Exception e) {
  } finally{
    heartBeatSender.stopHeartBeat(job); // stops heartbeat for this job
  }
}
```